# Flink process function back pressure issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a process function implemented in the Flink job, when large volume (10mil records) being injected, the process function seem to have locked down and caused the operators before and after it to paused and wait for a flush, exchanging interval.

[process function performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbYJg.jpg)

This seem like Flink source was on wait until the later operator freed out from busyness. Is this back pressures handling in Flink , is there anyway we may configure to let the stream flow without such interval wait?

Answer (score 0):

If the `process` is blocked, where would the data flow through to? The backpressure is not an explicit thing that Flink does (as far as I know). Rather it is a natural consequence of downstream operators not being able to accept any more data.

What it sounds like you need to do instead is see how you can make your job more parallel. This could be as simple as simply increasing your parallelism, but it may be more complex if your data is keyed and the issue is in fact that a key is receiving more data in a unit of time than can be processed efficiently. In that case you may need to have your key actually be such that your data is split across multiple partitions.

But without knowing the specifics of your application, this is all just speculation.

Comment: It ran with 60k unique key with 1kb each , also had tested the downstream can handled much higher throughput than the processfunction . It is possible that when the timer reached and flush out it will cause a lock, how does Flink internally works for this case?

Comment: Any idea or input? Still facing issue with the performance caused by this, and seem the larger the timer provided,the interval between flush just get bigger, and it worked like a batch now.

Comment: One thing to do is to see if each of your sub tasks are getting the same number of records. Perhaps some of the partitioning is uneven such that one of your sub-task threads is actually causing the others to block because it is processing too much data. Also keep in mind that if you are doing aggregate type operations, it must communicate this between Task Managers. So any bottleneck in network communication will cause you to get back pressure. You can see if all seem to have same amount of data flowing as well.

Comment: Hi @joshua , thanks for the points. Yes I did monitor the throughput of each taskmanager slot assigned and they seem evenly distributed. I also ensure there is sufficient unique keys in the test so it will not have data skewed .